# Ignore certain matches in preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace

Please find php string below :

```
$string = 'hi this is testing [ok i can remove it] and
then [ok i can remove it too] and then I want to spare [caption .... ]';
```

I want to remvoe [ok i can remove it] and [ok i can remove it too] but I want to retain [caption .... ] in the string using preg_replace. 
Current I am using following which is removing all with [ ]

```
$return = preg_replace( array('~\[.*]~'), '', $b );
```

kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of job, I'd use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
$string = 'hi this is testing [ok i can remove it] and then [ok i can remove it too] and then I want to spare [caption .... ]';
$return = preg_replace_callback(
           '~\[[^\]]*\]~', 
           function($m) {
               if (preg_match('/\bcaption\b/', $m[0]))
                   return $m[0];
               else
                   return '';
           }, 
           $string);
echo $return,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
hi this is testing  and then  and then I want to spare [caption .... ]
```